# Retrieve XML files, parse the data and print it off

Tags: python, xml, parsing, url, request

I am new to python and have been struggling with this task for quite a while. I have an input file with three URL's listed inside. I am wanting to fetch the XML document at the URL using requests and log an INFO message as I attempt to retrieve the URL and include the value as part of the message.
Here is the input file URL's

```
http://kitty.ninja/file1.xml
http://kitty.ninja/badurl.xml
http://kitty.ninja/file3.xml
```

And here is my code so far, I keep finishing with exit code:

```
import logging
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
r = requests.get('http://kitty.ninja/file1.xml')
print("Now attempting to get data at:", ('http://kitty.ninja/file1.xml'))
if r.status_code == 200:
  print("200 - Successfully retrieved:", ('http://kitty.ninja/file1.xml'))
  tree = ET.fromstring("hw8-input")
  root = tree.getroot()
  for customer in root.findall('customer'):
      name = customer.find('name').text
      checking_account = customer.find("checking_account").text
      try:
          savings_account = customer.find('savings_account').text
      except AttributeError:
          savings_account = "None"
      print(name, "Checking Account:", checking_account, "Savings Account:", savings_account)
elif r.status_code == 404:
  print("Resource not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different, more effective (IMHO) library. I simplified the code a bit:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(r.content)
```

From there the code is the same as in your question.

However, since this is an xml file, you are better off (again, IMHO) using xpath methods instead. It may not look like it makes much of a difference in this case, but where the xml gets seriously complicated (and it frequently does), xpath is far superior. The xpath methods would look like this (I replaced the try/except block with an if/else block, but it's just a personal preference):

```
for customer in root.xpath('//customer'):
    checking_account = customer.xpath("./checking_account")[0].text
    if len(customer.xpath('./savings_account'))>0:
        savings_account = customer.xpath('./savings_account')[0].text
    else:
        savings_account = "None"
    name = customer.xpath('./name')[0].text
    print(name, "Checking Account:", checking_account, "Savings Account:", savings_account)
```

In either case, the output is the same:

```
Susan Stone Checking Account: 465498435 Savings Account: None
Roger Roman Checking Account: 165498165 Savings Account: 64565435
Gary Grooman Checking Account: 654846546 Savings Account: None
Janet Jones Checking Account: 954387383 Savings Account: None
Nancy Noons Checking Account: 684981651 Savings Account: 5645648465
```

Comment: should I continue to use this flow for the other two URL's?

Comment: @Chainreaction Yes, for the last url. Don't know about the one in the middle ("file not found"), but if it has the same xml structure as the other two, it should work, too.

Answer (score 0):

@Jack Fleeting is right. Here is another solution for your reference.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
url = 'http://kitty.ninja/file1.xml'
html = req.get(url)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
for customer in doc.customers:
  print(customer.id.text,customer.name.text,customer.savings_account.text,customer.checking_accounts.text)
```

Result:

```
12 Susan Stone None ['465498435']
34 Roger Roman 64565435 ['165498165', '654684321']
56 Gary Grooman None ['654846546']
78 Janet Jones None ['954387383']
91 Nancy Noons 5645648465 ['684981651']
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples